# strftime error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

Am new to RubyOnRails, am getting strftime error on Heroku machine, Below code is heroku log for verification.

```
2014-08-03T15:15:06.051867+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert 
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into an exact number):
```

This code am using in my views/shared/events file

```
<%= Time.at(event_item.created_at).strftime("%d-%b-%Y") %>
```

This code in my local production machine work's fabulous, But not in heroku machine, am totally confuse, I think heroku wont support strftime, Is there any other method ? Waiting for your kind Help, Thanks in Advance.

Note: Using Postgresql for Database
      Ruby 1.9.3
      Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your time into `DateTime` before formatting it.

As you are showing date finally, I guess this should also work for you:

```
<%= event_item.created_at.to_datetime.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") %>
```

`Time.at()` seems useless here:

```
Time.at(event_item.created_at).class     # => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
event_item.created_at.class              # => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
event_item.created_at.to_datetime.class  # => DateTime
```

More about **[to_datetime](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime)**

Comment: Hi Raj, Great, Appreciated Lot, Thank you :)